# PHP Mysql total rows with FOUND_ROWS() and WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting x amount of rows from the db which are totalled with the 'totalRows'. From the rows I'd also like to total just those where the result column is equal to 'win'. I'm not seeing an answer either with the echo of 'totalWins'.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static function getList( $numRows=10000, $order="id DESC" ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table
        ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  $article = new Article( $row );
  $list[] = $article;
}

// Now get the total number of rows that matched the criteria
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
$totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
$conn = null;
return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );

// Now get the total number of rows WITH CONDITION matched
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalWins WHERE result = 'win'";
$totalWins = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
$conn = null;
return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalWins" => $totalWins[0] ) );
```

Comment: You're using placeholders `:numRows` with `mysql_` that will not work. That is PDO syntax and you're using `mysql_escape_string` --- You can't mix SQL APIs. Just do `ORDER BY $order LIMIT :numRows"`

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- have now updated. Any ideas on the problem?

Comment: You're welcome. That I couldn't pinpoint. See if the answer below will help.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalWins WHERE result = 'win'` is going to produce an error, not a result set. `FOUND_ROWS()` simply gives you an integer, it doesn't give you access to the table(s) in the previous query to do further filtering. Since you don't refer to any table in the statement, the column `result` is unknown to MySQL.

You can get both of your desired counts in one query, like so:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows, COUNT(*) AS totalWins FROM table WHERE result = 'win';
```

The `FOUND_ROWS()` function will look at `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` from the previous query, and return an integer. The rest of the query works just as it would without including the result of `FOUND_ROWS()` as a field in the result set.

Note that when you ask for a constant value (like the result of `FOUND_ROWS()`) as a field in your query, it will repeat for all rows in the query. On the other hand, when you ask for the result of an aggregate function (like `COUNT()`), your query result will be limited to just one row. These are potential "gotchas" - if it's not clear exactly what I mean here, try running these queries and examining their result sets (in order):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), result FROM table LIMIT 1000;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS(), result FROM table LIMIT 1000;
```

---

You're also using PDO with a function from the deprecated `mysql_` extension (`mysql_escape_string()`); better to stick with one API instead of mixing and matching. The documentation [lists `PDO::quote()` as an alternative](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table 
        ORDER BY " . $conn->quote($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";
```

Note that the documentation also [makes the following recommendation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php):

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
> strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements
> with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate
> user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound
> parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL
> injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated
> queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form
> of the query.

Comment: You left out the OP is mixing APIs ;-)

Comment: Ok that's great i've now chenged it to this but still not results, I'm guessing the last line is wrong: `$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows, COUNT(*) AS totalWinss FROM table WHERE result = 'win'";
    $totalWins = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0], "totalWins" => $totalWins[0] ) );`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not really familiar with these APIs. You're welcome to add more information in an edit or a separate answer; I can only really address the issues with the SQL.

Comment: @aphextwig Perhaps it's the typo in your SQL statement (`AS totalWinss`)?

Comment: @AirThomas I added the relevant information in an edit.

Comment: @aphextwig "Not working" can mean a lot of things, can you edit your question to add the most current version of your code, the result you want, the result you're getting, and any error messages you're seeing? That would be most helpful.

Comment: The code in my comment above is the latest version (minus the typo). Before the change I used to get a value for totalRows (7), now with the update I don't even get totalRows returned, it's just 0 instead of 7. In the code above I included `, "totalWins" => $totalWins[0]` but perhaps this is incorrect???

Comment: @aphextwig I was looking for the full code, as in the question. In your above comment, you store the `fetch()` result as `$totalWins`, but that result has both values in it. So you should name it something more general. The `$totalRows` variable doesn't exist because you never defined it. If you named your `fetch()` result `$row`, you could get your values like this: `return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $row["totalRows"], "totalWins" => $row["totalWins"] )`